# Trailing spaces not being removed even after using appropriate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am simply trying to remove trailing space from string variable.
Below is the sample code:

```
Set @Tree_ID='1.23     '

Set @Tree_ID = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Tree_ID))
```

But to my surprise , leading space is not getting removed. I did same separately and it worked fine. But somehow it is not trimming space inside my stored procedure.

Below is my stored procedure

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_Web_Calculate_Interest] -- 23,1,'2014-04-01','2015-03-19','','kiran.divate','COMP7',1

@FGRPNo int,
@Company_No int,

@From_Date datetime,
@To_Date datetime,
@CC_TID varchar(200),
@UserName varChar(100),
@HostName varChar(100),
@DispMode int=1

 As
 Begin
 Declare @Tree_ID char(30)
 Declare @TempTable Table(Group_No smallint,Company_No smallint,Group_Name    char(50),Tree_ID varchar(30),Is_Fixed char(1))

 If @FGRPNo > 0
 Begin
    if @DispMode =1
     Begin
       Insert into @TempTable(Group_No ,Company_No,Group_Name ,Tree_ID ,Is_Fixed ) 
        select distinct g.Group_No,g.Company_No, g.group_name,g.Tree_ID,g.Is_Fixed
          from account_group  G  inner join Account a 
        on a.Tree_ID like '%.' + ltrim(rtrim(CAST(g.Group_No as varchar(10))))  + '.%' 
            where (a.company_no=@Company_No  and a.account_no 
           in (  select Account_No 
          from Interest_Percent 
            where Company_No=@Company_No and Int_Rate >0 and effective_Date  between @From_Date and @To_Date) 

            and g.group_no=@FGRPNo


          and (g.company_no = 0 or g.company_no=@Company_No))

           order by g.group_no
    End
   Else
  Begin
                Insert into @TempTable(Group_No ,Company_No,Group_Name   ,Tree_ID ,Is_Fixed ) 
          select distinct g.Group_No,g.Company_No,    g.group_name,g.Tree_ID,g.Is_Fixed
           from account_group  G  inner join Account a 
            on a.Tree_ID like '%.' + ltrim(rtrim(CAST(g.Group_No as varchar(10))))  + '.%' 
            where (a.company_no=@Company_No  and a.account_no 
           in (  select Account_No 
          from Interest_Percent 
           where Company_No=@Company_No and Int_Rate >0 and effective_Date between @From_Date and @To_Date) 

               and g.Parent_group_no= @FGRPNo


           and (g.company_no = 0 or g.company_no=@Company_No))

             order by g.group_no

      End

  End
 Else
  Begin
             Insert into @TempTable(Group_No ,Company_No,Group_Name ,Tree_ID  ,Is_Fixed ) 
         select distinct g.Group_No,g.Company_No,  g.group_name,g.Tree_ID,g.Is_Fixed
            from account_group  G  inner join Account a 
             on a.Tree_ID like '%.' + ltrim(rtrim(CAST(g.Group_No as varchar(10))))  + '.%' 
             where (a.company_no=@Company_No  and a.account_no 
           in (  select Account_No 
         from Interest_Percent 
          where Company_No=@Company_No and Int_Rate >0 and effective_Date between @From_Date and @To_Date) 




       and (g.company_no = 0 or g.company_no=@Company_No))

       order by g.group_no
  End

 Declare @CompNo int

 Declare cur_temp SCROLL CURSOR FOR 

   Select Group_No ,Tree_ID,Company_No  from @TempTable 

 FOR READ ONLY

OPEN cur_temp 
FETCH first FROM cur_temp into @FGRPNo ,@Tree_ID,@CompNo
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
     Begin
     if @CompNo =0 
        Begin
         Set @Tree_ID = Convert(varchar(10),@Company_No) + '.' + @Tree_ID  
        end
        Set @Tree_ID = REPLACE(@Tree_ID, ' ', '')

        Exec SP_Calculate_Interest @FGRPNo,@Company_No,@Tree_ID,@From_Date,@To_Date,@CC_TID,@UserName,@HostName 
End

  Close cur_Temp

deallocate cur_Temp

--Exec SP_Web_GetAccountInterest @FGRPNo,@Tree_ID ,@UserName ,@HostName ,@Company_no  ,'G',@CC_TID ,@BalanceAmount output  ,@InterestAmount output  
--Select @BalanceAmount 
--Select @InterestAmount

if @DispMode >1
Begin
  Declare @TempTable2 Table(Account_No int,Account_Name char(50),Tree_ID char(30),parent_group_no smallint)

  Insert into @TempTable2(Account_No ,Account_Name,Tree_ID ,parent_group_no ) 
  select Distinct A.Account_No, A.Account_Name, A.Tree_ID, A.parent_group_no 
    from account A  Where A.parent_group_no = @FGRPNo  and A.company_no=@Company_No and a.account_no 
            in (select Account_No from Interest_Percent
             where Company_No=@Company_No  and Int_Rate >0 
             and effective_Date between @From_Date and @To_Date) order by A.Account_No

    Declare @Acc_No int 
    Declare cur_temp2 SCROLL CURSOR FOR 

    Select Account_No ,Tree_ID  from @TempTable2 

    FOR READ ONLY

        OPEN cur_temp2 
        FETCH first FROM cur_temp2 into @Acc_No ,@Tree_ID
        WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
             Begin

                Set @Tree_ID = REPLACE(@Tree_ID, ' ', '')
                    Exec SP_Calculate_Interest @Acc_No,@Company_No,@Tree_ID,@From_Date,@To_Date,@CC_TID,@UserName,@HostName 
                End

        Close cur_Temp2

        deallocate cur_Temp2

End


End
```

Below part of code :

```
  if @CompNo =0 
    Begin
     Set @Tree_ID = Convert(varchar(10),@Company_No) + '.' + @Tree_ID  
    end
    Set @Tree_ID = REPLACE(@Tree_ID, ' ', '')
```

Value of @Tree_ID at `Set @Tree_ID = Convert(varchar(10),@Company_No) + '.' + @Tree_ID` is 1.23 with trailing spaces, so should it not remove space right after if statement ends when I do `Set @Tree_ID = REPLACE(@Tree_ID, ' ', '')`
But when I added watch in debugger, it is still same!!

Comment: What version of SqlServer you are using? In SqlServer 2008R2 your code running correctly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code.   The error probably lies in your analysis of the results.

Comment: @TabAlleman I debugged code, I am receiving value properly, but right after I use replace or trim function, value is still unchanged !!

Comment: Well it's working for everybody else but you, so either your copy of SQL server is defective or you're doing something wrong, but we can't see over your shoulder to tell what it is.

Comment: Yeah, it is working for me when I am using it separately, but I just don't understand why is it not working. Now unfortunately there is no way I can exactly show you what I am dong

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody Look at my unpdated answer.

Comment: Instead of the debugger, what happens if you put a PRINT @Tree_ID right after the REPLACE() statement?

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.   Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Tree_ID` is a `char(30)`. So always 30 characters no matter how you trim or replace spaces.

You could try a varchar instead. `Declare @Tree_ID varchar(30)`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:   The problem is that @Tree_ID is using datatype CHAR(30)!

CHAR always fills with enough space to use its full length.   If you don't want trailing spaces you need to use VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx).

```
SELECT REPLACE(@Tree_ID, ' ', '')
```

Try to use this:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Tree_ID, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')))
```

Comment: I surely can, but I am pondering why exactly is my code not working!

Comment: For some hidden reasons this didnt work also, also I know it should work fine

Comment: Could you provide what exactly words are printing correctly and which of them are wrong?

Comment: Check my SP now, well, exacly @TreeID is not trimming properly

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody Check my updated answer and tell me If that works for you.

Comment: I tried, it didnt solve, and i dont think problem lies in procedure of trimming spaces, but there is something which i am missing

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Tree_ID varchar(100)
Set @Tree_ID='1.23     '

Set @Tree_ID = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Tree_ID))

print '|'+@Tree_ID+'|'
```

Result : `|1.23|`

It works just fine, but as a advice. Be carefull for tab spaces or enter spaces ( for example when the text was taken from a Memo )

See this ex with TAB space :

```
declare @Tree_ID varchar(100)
Set @Tree_ID='1.23      '

Set @Tree_ID = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Tree_ID))

print '|'+@Tree_ID+'|'
```

Comment: As I said, it worked fine for me also when I tried like this, but somehow same code inside SP is not working! And it is just same chunk of code there aswell

Comment: Post the SP code, most likely the problem is not from this part of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION RemovewhiteSpaces
    (
        @InputStr varchar(8000)
    )
    RETURNS varchar(8000)
    AS
    BEGIN
    declare @ResultStr varchar(8000)
    set @ResultStr = @InputStr
    while charindex(' ', @ResultStr) > 0
        set @ResultStr = replace(@InputStr, ' ', '')

    return @ResultStr
    END

select dbo.RemoveAllSpaces('1.23    1 ')

RESULT 
1.231
```

and apply in your store procedure ...MAY BE IT WORKS FINE

Answer (score 0):

Guys I replaced below code :

```
 Declare @Tree_ID char(30)
```

With :

```
 Declare @Tree_ID varchar(30)
```

And it worked fine for me. So, it means there was no problem with either of `LTRIM`,`RTRIM` or `Replace` functions which were not working on static allocation (`char`) and when I changed it to `varchar` it worked fine